# Getting error while consuming Web API in Xamarin forms cross platform

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Getting below error while consuming web API in Xamarin forms "Cannot convert from Login to System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption"

I'm new to mobile development ,please help me in completing the above code for consuming the API's in Xamarin cross platform.

Below is the code for WEB API

```
public class DBLoginController : ApiController
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_test"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = null;

        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("getCustomerInfo")]
        public DataTable Get()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_admin";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt.TableName = "tbl_admin";
                adp.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return dt;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public int Login([System.Web.Http.FromBody] Login lgn)
        {
            int ret = 0;
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from tbl_admin where username='"+lgn.username+"'username and password='"+ lgn.password + "'";

                cmd.Connection = con;
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Open();
                ret = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return ret;
        }
}
```

Below is the code for consuming API in xamarin form

```
private async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://********.com/api/DBLogin/getCustomer");
                    Login lgn = new Login { username = txtUsername.Text.ToString(), password = txtPassword.Text.ToString() };
                    var response =  client.GetAsync("api/Login/Login").Result;
                    var a = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (a.Result.ToString().Trim() == "0")
                    {
                        messageLabel.Text = "Invalid login credentials.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      await  Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

please help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: your Login API requires a `Login` parameter, but you client is using an HttpGet with no parameters

Comment: @Jason, Sir I'm new to web api's please help me in completing the code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Google `How To Fetch Data Using Web API in Xamarin.Forms` , check the tutorial to see if it helps.

Comment: I have gone through many videos and searched on google also, I'm new to mobile development and Web API's, so please help me to complete the above code.Thanks in advance

Comment: It is well explained in official documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest and sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-todorest/ , have you checked them ?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT ,yes I have gone through the above sites. I'm trying to login to Mobile app using remote database , please help me,Thanks